# For absolutely convergent series, when applicable, why do the ratio test and root test yield the same limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So looking back at this problem: [$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } (\frac{(n+1)^{2n^2+2n+1}}{(n+2)^{(n+1)^2}\cdot n^{n^2}})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266675/lim-n-rightarrow-infty-fracn12n22n1n2n12-cdot-nn/2266681#2266681) , I did a while ago, I thought of something rather interesting. The author of that problem originally got it from using the ratio test on a series. Now, I used the root test on that series, and got 1/e as my answer. Of course, if one evaluates the above limit by brute force, they will also yield 1/e as an answer. So that makes me wonder, why is this so?

tl;dr - **For an absolutely convergent series, why is it that the root test and the ratio test give the same exact limit as n -> infinity? As a follow up question, is there ever an instance (for an absolutely convergent series), where the root and ratio test wouldn't result in the same limit?**

Comment: Relevant: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0025570x33450.di021200.02p0190s.pdf (middle of first page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The improved ratio test says that given a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}$ with $x_{n}\geq0$ for all
$n\in\mathbb{N}$, if$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_{n}}<1,
$$
then the series converges, while if
$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_{n}}>1,
$$
then the series diverges to $\infty$.
On the other hand, the ratio test says that given a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}$ with $x_{n}>0$ for all
$n\in\mathbb{N}$, if$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}<1,
$$
then the series converges. If
$$
\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}>1,
$$
then the series diverges to $\infty$.
Now given a sequence $\left\{  x_{n}\right\}  $
of real numbers, with $x_{n}>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then (see [inequalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178272/finding-limit-of-a-given-sequence-using-inequalities)
$$
\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}\leq\liminf
\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_{n}}\leq\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow
\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_{n}}\leq\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}
}{x_{n}}.
$$
All the inequalities can be strict. It follows that if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}=\ell$ exists then there exists $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow
\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_{n}}=\ell,$ so the two tests give the same result. 
However in general the the ratio test is worse
than the root test. 
Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}$, where $$
x_{n}=\left\{
\begin{array}
[c]{ll}%
\frac{1}{2^{n}} & \text{if }n\text{ is even,}\\
\frac{1}{3^{n}} & \text{if }n\text{ is odd.}%
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then $$
\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}=0,\quad
\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}=\infty,
$$
and so the ratio test gives NO information. However,$$
\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_{n}}=\frac{1}{2},
$$
and so the series converges by the root test.

Comment: (+1) Well constructed tutorial.  You might consider adding a reference such as [This One](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178272/finding-limit-of-a-given-sequence-using-inequalities/2178670#2178670) that proves that $$ \liminf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le \liminf (a_n)^ {1/n}\le\limsup (a_n)^ {1/n}\le \limsup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

Comment: thanks. I just added the link